# Upload image to SQL database from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upload an image to a SQL database using ASP.NET MVC. The database `BeforeImage` remains as null although I am receiving no error a few file sizes and formats. Thanks

```
 public class Job
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte[] BeforeImage { get; set; }
    public byte[] AfterImage { get; set; }
  }
```

View model:

```
public class BeforePhotoVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase BeforeImage { get; set; }
}
```

Get:

```
 public ActionResult AddBefore(int? id)
 {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var job = db.Jobs.Find(id);
        var BeforeVM = new BeforePhotoVM();

        //vm = db.Jobs.Find(id);
        return View("Job2", BeforeVM);
}
```

Post:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddBefore([Bind(Include = "ID,BeforeImage")] BeforePhotoVM BeforeVM)
{
    var job = db.Jobs.Find(BeforeVM.ID);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       byte[] BeforeImage = new byte[BeforeVM.BeforeImage.InputStream.Length];
       BeforeVM.BeforeImage.InputStream.Read(BeforeImage, 0, BeforeImage.Length);

       job.BeforeImage = BeforeImage;

       db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();

       return RedirectToAction("AddBefore", new { id = job.ID });
    }

    return View("Job");
}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/708140/Uploading-and-Viewing-Images-With-ASP-Net-MVC-and

Comment: Thanks, I've read a fair bit and followed some things like this. This is for MungoDB though and my error is specific to my application.

Comment: Can you show the code for the Job2 view?

Comment: Sorry, It works perfectly. It was VS Sever explorer not showing updated table even after close connection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look, you are doing too many things for something that should be simple.
Plus, next time, post ur html code with ur ajax.

Let me try to help you.

At your asp.net page.

your Html.Begin form should have the enctype = "multipart/form-data"

like this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Here goes ur action", "Here goes ur controller", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "something with sucess" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

with that in mind
lets got to ur model

```
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

ok ... now lets finish with the controller

```
        public ActionResult Cadastro(YOURMODEL _model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        _model.Photo = new byte[file.ContentLength];
```

see, ur controller recives the HttpPostedFileBase and u can access creating a new byte.. but remember.. in ur asp.net code the file name has to be the same in ur controller as it bellow

The rest is with u
Hope this will help you.